# Jquery, select id then select partially similar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to make it so when you click on a particular image, that image will hide, then it's corresponding youtube video iframe will show and slide down. I've already made this work BUT I would like to condense this code so I don't have to enter it in for each image/video combination. How would I go about turning this into just one short bit of code that automatically applies to images with #something_click and matching video with #something_slide?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$('#abcd_click').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
$('#abcd_slide').before("<br />").slideDown('slow');
});

$('#efgh_click').click(function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
$(this).hide();
$('#efgh_slide').before("<br />").slideDown('slow');
});
```

On and on and on and on.........

EDIT: Not sure if this is the best, cleanest or fastest way, but I did get this to do the trick using a combination of some of the answers. Thanks to all!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('img[id$="_click"]').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        var videoID = thisId.split('_')[0];
        $(this).hide();
        $('#'+videoID+'_slide').before('<br />').slideDown('slow');   
   });        
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Create a function with the id as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do this for all images on your page, here is one way of doing this generically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('img').click(function(evt) {
        var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(thisId && thisId.indexOf("_click") != -1)
        {
           var videoId = thisId.split("_")[0];
           evt.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide();
            $("#"+videoId+"_slide").before("<br />").show().slideDown('slow');

        }
    });
});​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgGBL/1/) is an example fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Use class names instead of IDs. That's what they're for.

Comment: or if absolutley necessary to use id then he can use the ends with selector.

Comment: "ends-with" selectors are much, much slower than class name selectors.

Comment: You need to be more specific, or else he'll end up sliding down ALL the videos instead of just the one desired.

Comment: He already seems to know how to use $(this). Let's hope for the best :)

Comment: So let's say I do, and I just have .something_click and .something_slide... If I click one, all of the iframes will slide down, and I don't want that to happen. Where do I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: @Diodeus hence why I said if it is absolutley necessary.  I've had a couple of situations where I have uneditable html but written a javascript file to alter it in some way.  In these sorts of situations you have no way of adding in classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ends with" selector:

```
$('[id$="_click"]')
```

The above grabs all elements with id that ends with "_click".

Answer (score 0):

Assign a common class and a `data-` attribute to the element with `id=abcd_click`, call it `data-slide`, and use it to store the ID of the element you want to slide. Then use `.data()` to retrieve it. With this approach, you can use one single event handler for all instances:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="clicker" id="abcd_click" data-slide="abcd_slide">
    <img src="whatever.gif">
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.clicker').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $('#'+$(this).data('slide')).before("<br />").slideDown('slow');
});
```